# Bingo Card Game Issue With Repeating Random Integers

Tags: java

I have this static method created for a Bingo game.

```
public static void bingoCard(){

    int [][]card = new int [5][5];
    ArrayList<Integer> alreadyUsed = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    boolean valid = false;

    // First row
    for(int row = 0; row < card.length; row++){
        int tmp = 0;
        while(!valid){
            tmp = (int)(Math.random()*15)+1;
            if(!alreadyUsed.contains(tmp)){
                valid = true;
                alreadyUsed.add(tmp);
            }
        }
        card[row][0] = tmp;
        valid = false;
    }

    // Second row
    for(int row = 0; row < card.length; row++){
        int tmp = 0;
        while(!valid){
            tmp = (int)(Math.random()*15)+1;
            if(!alreadyUsed.contains(tmp)){
                valid = true;
                alreadyUsed.add(tmp);
            }
        }
        card[row][1] = tmp;
        valid = false;
    }

    // Third row
    for(int row = 0; row < card.length; row++){
        int tmp = 0;
        while(!valid){
            tmp = (int)(Math.random()*15)+1;
            if(!alreadyUsed.contains(tmp)){
                valid = true;
                alreadyUsed.add(tmp);
            }
        }
        card[row][2] = tmp;
        valid = false;
    }

    card[2][2] = 0; // The 3rd matrix to the left and right is a 0.

    // Fourth row
    for(int row = 0; row < card.length; row++){
        int tmp = 0;
        while(!valid){
            tmp = (int)(Math.random()*15)+1;
            if(!alreadyUsed.contains(tmp)){
                valid = true;
                alreadyUsed.add(tmp);
            }
        }
        card[row][3] = tmp;
        valid = false;
    }

    // Fifth row
    for(int row = 0; row < card.length; row++){
        int tmp = 0;
        while(!valid){
            tmp = (int)(Math.random()*15)+1;
            if(!alreadyUsed.contains(tmp)){
                valid = true;
                alreadyUsed.add(tmp);
            }
        }
        card[row][4] = tmp;
        valid = false;
    }

    // Creates an array to make title

    String title[] = {"B","I","N","G","O"};
    for(int i = 0; i < title.length;i++){
        System.out.print(title[i] + "\t");
    }

    System.out.println();

    for(int row = 0; row < card.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < card[row].length; col++){
            System.out.print(card[row][col] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

In the output, this piece of code outputs to this console bingo card: http://puu.sh/487mz/939c8d7a59.png

My main issue is that repeating digits. I am interested in knowing how to get rid of the repeating digits within the 5x5 arrays. Thank you!

Second EDIT: I am also interested in having the game play by itself. Meaning, it would pull out random numbers and correspond to whether or not the digits are on the board. If the condition is met for a BINGO condition, then do something. Does anyone have suggestions in regards to this?

Comment: `Set` doesn't allow duplicates, consider using some class that implements it.

Comment: I am confused. How do I convert the entire array to a set and back? I need to implement further functionality later on, AKA, a method to actually play the game, or the array.

Comment: Why so many nested loops? You should be able to remove all "row" loops and group all "col" loops inside 1 "row" loop. Afterward, you can call `card[2][2]=0;` just once.

Comment: @Saviour Self - already addressed in my answer, but yes!

Comment: @Andrew_CS Just noticed it after I commented.

Comment: To address your uniqueness problem, I would consider this: Instead of setting the array value, run a loop on a list: while (list.size() < 5) { number = Math.random(); if (list.contains(number) continue; else list.add(number);}  Once you have your 5 numbers, run a loop to set the array values to the numbers in the list.

Comment: Your original question was answered, your new question is a completely different topic and should have it's own post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to have another data structure that holds all random numbers that have been generated and added into the 2D array that represents the card.

After creating a random number you could check to see if that number already exists in the data structure.  If it does then generate a different number.  If it doesn't then add it to the card and the data structure.

An ArrayList would be good to use here since it has a nice contains method already written for you.  Here's an example.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

int [][]card = new int [5][5];
ArrayList<Integer> alreadyUsed = new ArrayList<Integer>();
boolean valid = false;

for(int row = 0; row < card.length; row++){
    int tmp = 0;
    while(!valid){
        tmp = (int)(Math.random()*15)+1;
        if(!alreadyUsed.contains(tmp)){
            valid = true;
            alreadyUsed.add(tmp);
        }
    }
    card[row][0]= tmp;
    valid = false;
}
```

Also in all of your nested for loops you never use the variable col.  You could simply get rid of the inner for loop in each of these nested loops.

```
for(int row=0; row < card.length; row++){
    for(int col=0; col < card[row].length; col++){
        card[row][0]=(int)(Math.random()*15)+1;
    }
}
```

Could be changed to

```
for(int row=0; row < card.length; row++){
    card[row][0]=(int)(Math.random()*15)+1;
}
```

Also `card[2][2]=0;` only needs to happen once, here you're setting it multiple times.  This could be changed from

```
for(int row=0;row<card.length;row++){
    for(int col=0;col<card[row].length;col++){
        card[row][2]=(int)(Math.random()*15)+31;
        card[2][2]=0;
    }
}
```

To

```
for(int row=0;row<card.length;row++){
    card[row][2]=(int)(Math.random()*15)+31;
}

card[2][2]=0;
```

Comment: Thank you my friend for the suggested edits. I have followed your advice.

Comment: I added an example of how to check for if numbers have been used already.

Comment: Interesting. Do you suggest me to use arrayList versus what I have now?

Comment: You would keep your 2D array the same, the arrayList is just for checking if numbers have been used already.

Comment: Ah sorry, I can clearly see that now. I am getting an error saying `tmp` is not initialized in `card[row][0] = tmp;`. That seems to be an issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36036/discussion-between-thegreencabbage-and-andrew-cs)

Answer (score 3):

When I've written BINGO boards, I have made an ArrayList containing all possible unique values, then made a call to `Collections.shuffle( mylist)` which will randomly re-order the values.  Then you can iterate over the list to populate your matrix.

Just make sure you re-shuffle for each new board you make

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the random function like that - instead, fill up an array or ArrayList with all of the potential random numbers. Then randomly remove numbers from that - that will ensure that you cannot get repeated numbers, as only one of each exists.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class which represents a bingo table.  Populate an array with numbers from 0 to 99. When generating a new table, shuffle this array and pull numbers from it in order.

```
public class BingoBoard{
    Integer[] randomNumbers;
    int[][] grid = new int[5][5];
    public BingoBoard(){
        randomNumbers = new Integer[100];
        for(int i=0;i<randomNumbers.length;i++)
            randomNumbers[i] = i;
        populateCard();
    }

    public void set(int x, int y, int value){
        grid[x][y] = value;
    }

    public void populateCard(){
        //randomize the numbers you'll pull from.
        //Array.asList will be backed by randomNumbers, so this works.
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(randomNumbers));
        for(int x=0;x<5;x++){
            for(int y=0;y<5;y++){
                int num = randomNumbers[x+y*5];
                set(x,y,num);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a very efficient way to populate your grid with random values.

Comment: This code is very interesting, but doesn't work -- It has 2 flaws: 1) The `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(randomNumbers));` line will do nothing, and will cause your data to come out in sequential order. Reason being is because it must be called on an `Integer [] randomNumbers` or reference type, and not a primitive type `int`. 2) Once this error is corrected, this will generate purely random, unique numbers on a bingo board, but not not within the column boundaries as OP expects. Eg: You can get 99 in column B, but it should only have the numbers 1-15.

Comment: You're wrong on 1st point, right on 2nd. `Arrays.asList` returns a list backed by the input array. [Check the doc again.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...))

Comment: Hmm... Can't seem to get it working: With `int`: http://ideone.com/7rXr9o   With `Integer`: http://ideone.com/NjXdC7

Comment: Wow I apologize, *I* was wrong. Didn't fully understand Arrays.asList. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

you could keep a list of visited random numbers generated and check it before adding this number to the game like this

```
boolean[] visited = new boolean[100];
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i ++) visited[i] = false;
```

and inside each loop use this

```
for(int row=0; row < card.length; row++){
int num = (int)(Math.random()*15)+1;
    if visited[num]{
        row --;
        continue;
    }
    visited[num] = true;
    card[row][0] = num;
}
```

Comment: Hi amdorra. I have removed the `col` section of my code as suggested by another user, since it wasn't doing anything. Could you suggest me ways to implement what you have with that removed?

Comment: i updated the code, check it out if you have any questions don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thanks! I also think you mean `visited[i] = false;` versus `boolean[i] = false;` I presume?

Comment: You need a loop where you check your visited array too. Also this approach won't work every time.

Answer (score 0):

Fill an `ArrayList` with numbers from `1` to `N`, then use a `java.util.Random` to pick/remove numbers (shuffle is not necessary):

```
ArrayList<Integer> card = new ArrayList<Integer>(N);
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
   card.add(i + 1);

Random random = Random();
int pick = card.remove(random.nextInt(card.size()));
```

You could easily wrap this into a class to organize things.

Comment: Don't need to add and remove elements if you shuffle the structure with `Collections.shuffle`. Just a tip.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I would have implemented it.

```
    int[][] board = new int[5][5];
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int number = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int increment = 1;
    int col = 0;

    //Run a loop until you're at your last column.
    while (col < board.length) {

        //Ensure uniqueness of your numbers
        while (list.size() < 5) {
            number = (int) (Math.random() * 15) + increment;
            if (!list.contains(number))
                list.add(number);
        }

        //Add elements to the array.
        for (int i : list)
            board[index++][col] = i;

        //Set values for the next iteration.
        index = 0;
        increment += 15;
        list.clear();
        col++;
    }
    board[2][2] = 0;

    //Print the board.
    System.out.println("B\tI\tN\tG\tO\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            System.out.print(board[i][j] + "\t");
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Results:

```
B   I   N   G   O

9   29  34  59  62  
8   23  44  52  64  
7   16  0   53  63  
1   19  33  46  71  
15  17  41  58  61
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, just use this.

```
    int element = 5;
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(element);

    for (int i = 1; i <= element * element; i++)
        numbers.add(i);

     Collections.shuffle(numbers);

    int[][] numArr = new int[element][element];

    for (int i = 0, counter = 0; i < element; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < element; j++, counter++)
            numArr[i][j] = numbers.get(counter);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < numArr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numArr[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%-5d", numArr[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```